# Conflict between Jquery Mobile and Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/files/jQueryRotate.2.1.js"></script>
```

I want to use the image resize and drag function of Jquery UI in a Jquery Mobile-based page, but after adding Jquery UI lib in the page, all Jquery Mobile CSS lost effect.

Anyone got any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: jquery ui or mobile dont have an option for noConflict-mode.

Comment: hye .. can u just change the .js file above the css.. make the css below js